# Efficient assembly check on multiple bits

Tags: assembly, logic, bit

I have some value in AX and need to check on multiple bits at a time.
Let's say I want to check the first and the last bits and the others are DC values.
that what I did, but it's so inefficient as I am checking for multiple times for different values.

```
AND AX,8001H
CMP AX,8001H
JE
```

I have thought about only ANDing and jumping based on the parity but using MASM the parity is for the first 8 bits only so...

Comment: So in this case you want the jump taken only if both bits are set?

Comment: yeah and Whatever the other bits are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if both bits are set, I'm afraid you always need two instructions (not counting the conditional jump). Your own approach takes up 6 bytes:

```
25 01 80          AND   AX,8001H
3D 01 80          CMP   AX,8001H
```

You can save a byte by using `NOT`; it inverts all bits (making `CMP` unnecessary), and it is only 2 bytes in size.

```
F7 D0             NOT   AX
25 01 80          AND   AX,8001H
```

If the instructions are in a loop being executed many times, *and* you have a register to spare, then you can save another byte. The total amount of code is more, but because you can keep part of it outside the loop, it should be slightly faster.

```
BB 01 80          MOV   BX,8001H   ; keep this outside the loop
...               ...
F7 D0             NOT   AX
21 D8             AND   AX,BX
```

**EDIT:**
One final possibility for improvement. If you are always testing for one or more bits being *set*, then you might want to flip the meaning of zeroes and ones throughout your function, possibly even throughout the entire program. There is no law against defining zero as true, one as false. (In digital circuits, you actually see this a lot.) Then you can drop `NOT AX`, saving you two more bytes. What's more, you can replace `AND` by the non-destructive `TEST`, allowing you to perform multiple tests without the need to save and restore `AX`. To judge whether or not this is possible in your particular case, I would have to see more of your code.

Comment: It's bad that i am done with the program. i will for sure try and consider your "edit" part and the NOT and then AND seems better. as mentioned by @PhiS the ANDN seems just perfect and also the PEXT is good i wonder if there is a non destructive ANDN
Thanks a lot u helped me

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, I think [Ruud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21345031/69588) is right on track. But if you are coding for a recent (e.g. Haswell) CPU that supports the new [Bit Manipulation Instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets) (BMI1, BMI2, also see [Intel Manuals](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf)) then - depending on the code context - some of these new instructions might be helpful.

In particular, assuming your `Mask = 8001h` there is now the `ANDN` instruction that could be used like such (like Ruud's answer):

```
andn eax, eax, Mask ; Mask can be reg32 or mem32
jz ...
```

Under certain conditions, also `PEXT` might be useful:

```
pext DEST, eax, Mask    ; Mask can be in reg32 or mem32 / DEST is a reg32
    ; Mask ... 10000000 00000001b = 8001h
    ; EAX  ... Yyyyyyyy xxxxxxxXb
    ; DEST ... 00000000 000000YXb
    ; Flags NOT affected!
cmp DEST, 11b
je ...
```

*Disclaimer: I don't have a Haswell CPU here, so the above code is speculation on my part based on reading the Intel docs*

Comment: Thanks for updating my ancient 8086 knowledge! +1